# Why do these two HTML canvas with same width and height return with different height for the second one?

Tags: html

How do I make these two canvases to be of same width and height?
I do not know why they are being in different size even though their width and height are the same.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid #000000"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" heigt="300" style="border: 1px solid #000000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo at the `height` attribute of the second element

```
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" heigt="300" style="border: 1px solid #000000"></canvas>
```

should be

```
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid #000000"></canvas>
```